# Preserve the non-numerical columns when doing pandas.DataFrame.groupby().sum()

Tags: python, pandas

Can I preserve the non-numerical columns (the 1st appeared value) when doing pandas.DataFrame.groupby().sum() ?

For example, I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['aa1', 'aa2', 'aa1', 'aa2'],'B' : ['bb1', 'bbb1', 'bb2', 'bbb2'],'C' : ['cc1', 'ccc2', 'ccc3', 'ccc4'],'D' : [1, 2, 3, 4],'E' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})
>>> df
     A     B     C  D  E
0  aa1   bb1   cc1  1  1
1  aa2  bbb1  ccc2  2  2
2  aa1   bb2  ccc3  3  3
3  aa2  bbb2  ccc4  4  4
>>> df.groupby(["A"]).sum()
     D  E
A        
aa1  4  4
aa2  6  6
```

Following is the result I want to obtain:

```
     B    C    D  E
A        
aa1  bb1  cc1  4  4
aa2  bbb1 ccc2 6  6
```

Notice that the value of column `B` and `C`  is the first associated B value and C value of each group key.

Comment: Are you saying you want to group by `A` and sort by `B in reverse` it is a little confusing and can you explain your expected result with your available df.

Comment: Actually I want to add the column `B` to the result of `df.groupby(["A"]).sum()`, and  the result `B` value is the first `B` value of the groups.

Comment: Hi @AaronWang, welcome to stackoverflow! I believe you wanted to use the word preserve instead of reserve, if so please edit your question so it will be easy for others with a similar issue to find in the future. Also, as you said in the comments please include in your post "you want to find the first associated B value of each group key". Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each key in the groupby-sum dataframe, look up the key in the original dataframe and put the associated value of column `B` into a new column.

```
#groupby and sum over columns C and D
df_1 = df.groupby(['A']).sum()
```

**Find the first values in column B associated with groupby keys**

```
groupby keys
col_b = []
#iterate through keys and find the the first value in df['B'] with that key in column A
for i in df_1.index:
    col_b.append(df['B'][df['A'] == i].iloc[0])

#insert list of values into new dataframe
df_1.insert(0, 'B', col_b)
>>>df_1
      B  D  E
A           
aa1 bb1  4  4
aa2 bbb1 6  6
```

Comment: Can I reserve the all non-numerical columns when I doing pandas.DataFrame.groupby().sum()

Comment: @AaronWang Can you please edit your question, to better reflect what you mean? I've edited my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Yes, you get it. Thanks! The code may be a little bit 'ugly' but useful. If I have a lot of columns like B, the code will be more complicate. Now I don't think there is an api for this function in pandas, hahah

Answer (score 7):

Just use 'first':

```
df.groupby(["A"]).agg({'B': 'first',
                       'C': 'first',
                       'D': sum,
                       'E': sum})
```

Answer (score 4):

Grouping only on column 'A' gives:

```
df.groupby(['A']).sum()

        C     D
A              
bar  1.26  0.88
foo  0.92 -4.19
```

Grouping on column 'A' and 'B' gives:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()

            C     D
A   B                
bar one    1.38 -0.73
    three  0.26  0.80
    two   -0.38  0.81
foo one    1.96 -2.72
    three -0.42 -0.18
    two   -0.62 -1.29
```

If you want only the column 'B' that has 'one' you can do:

```
d = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False).sum()
d[d.B=='one'].set_index('A')

    B     C     D
A                   
bar  one  1.38 -0.73
foo  one  1.96 -2.72
```

I'm not sure I understand but is this what you want to do?
Note: I increased the output precision just to get the same numbers shown in the post.

```
d = df.groupby('A').sum()
d['B'] = 'one'
d.sort_index(axis=1)

       B         C         D
A                           
bar  one  1.259069  0.876959
foo  one  0.921510 -4.193397
```

If you want to put the first sorted value of the column from 'B' instead you can use:

```
d['B'] = df.B.sort(inplace=False)[0]
```

So here I replaced 'one','two','three' with 'a', 'b','c' to see if this is what you are trying to do, and use insert() method as suggested by other post

```
df

    A  B         C         D
0  foo  a  0.638362 -0.931817
1  bar  a  1.380706 -0.733307
2  foo  b -0.324514  0.203515
3  bar  c  0.258534  0.803298
4  foo  b -0.299485 -1.495979
5  bar  b -0.380171  0.806968
6  foo  a  1.324810 -1.792996
7  foo  c -0.417663 -0.176120

d = df.groupby('A').sum()
d.insert(0, 'B', df.B.sort(inplace=False)[0])
d

    B         C         D
A                         
bar  a  1.259069  0.876959
foo  a  0.921510 -4.193397
```

Comment: Actually I want to add the column `B` to the result of `df.groupby(["A"]).sum()`, and  the result `B` value is the first `B` value of the groups.

The values of `C` and `D` are not what I want in `d[d.B=='one'].set_index('A')`, and `B`'s value may not always be "one", its value is the first `B` value of `df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()`

Comment: The 'desired values' as posted are the same as grouping on 'A' only. I assume the desired result is to group on both A and B, but only select out column B that has 'one'. If the desired result is to group only on 'A' and then insert a new column 'B' that has 'one' in each entry that can be done also.

Comment: @AaronWang I think I understand please check final edit above

Comment: Yes, you get it. Thanks! The code may be 'ugly'  but useful. If I have a lot of columns like `B`, the code will be more complicate. Now I don't think there is an api for this function in pandas, hahah

Comment: @SteveMisuta If you do a sort, you won't get the corresponding first value of each group, but just the first 2 values of column B.

Comment: @AaronWang notice i used [0] after the sort statement to only take the first value

Comment: @imp9 my understanding is the groupby will group alphabetically by default for strings so if you sort column B and then take the first value (index [0]) that will also be the first value of the group, not the first two values of column B.

Answer (score 1):

All these answers seem pretty wordy; the Pandas doc [1] also doesn't seem clear on this point despite giving an SQL example on the first page:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, mean(Column3), sum(Column4)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Column1, Column2
```

which will choose the "first" of Column1, Column2, while Pandas does not. As OP points out the non-numeric columns are simply dropped. My solution is not that pretty either, but perhaps more control is Pandas' design goal:

```
agg_d = { c: 'sum' if c == 'A' else 'first' for c in df.columns }
df = df.groupby( df['A'] ).agg( agg_d )
```

this maintains all non-numeric columns, like sql does. This is basically the same as Phillip's answer below, but without needing to explicitly enumerate the columns.

NOTES

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html